# Python: Approaches to parse English sentences: Regex?

Tags: python, regex, parsing

I have to process a bunch of sentences (assume well-formed English) such as:

"Humpty dumpty sat on a wall i.e. humpty was sitting on a wall! Then, he fell down. Why did he fall?"

I am interested in two things:

1. Words (so commas, semicolons, etc. are ignored)
2. Where a particular sentence terminates (I'd think on `!`, `?` and `.`, but there is further complication of "i.e." which has dots in it)

Given the statement has words such as "i.e.", using a generic regex to skip "\W+" does not work out of the box.

Is regex a good way of accomplishing the above 2 things? If it is, can someone give me pointers to getting started with creating such a regex? **OR** should I create my own rules for finding the end of the sentences?

Example of a rule would be:

> If the sentence ends in `.` or `?` or `!` **AND** there is a space after that **AND** the next word starts with a capital letter, then the previous sentence ended.

This rule fails if the sentence has "Dr. John went home." (`.` and space after r in Dr. followed by "J" in capital falsely signals beginning of a new sentence)

Comment: In case of 'i.e.' and 'Dr. John' you could make a set of 'not ending' that checks for them before setting a sentence with a ending. You'd have to hand pick them tho.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your example text is ill-structured, as the first sentence is not grammatically correct.

Do you have to use regex? Or are you just looking for a good library for parsing text to find whole sentences?

I would recommend TextBlob for parsing text. Here is an example:

```
from textblob import TextBlob
blob = TextBlob("Humpty dumpty sat on a wall i.e. humpty was sitting on a wall! Then, he fell down. Dr. John (BA in Medical Engineering) helped reconstruct humpty?")
blob.sentences

# [Sentence("Humpty dumpty sat on a wall i.e."),
#  Sentence("humpty was sitting on a wall!"),
#  Sentence("Then, he fell down."),
#  Sentence("Dr. John (BA in Medical Engineering) helped reconstruct humpty?")]
```

Comment: actually i just tried TextBlob and i.e. does not get treated properly...it assumes the sentence ends in i.e. which is incorrect

Comment: nevermind, i take it back , the textblob works just fine, i.e. should be followed by a comma to be in correct english!